# Notepad++ Delete Lines with Find & Replace

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, newlines

Does anyone know how to delete a line using Find & Replace in Notepad++ ?

In my Find query it finds the proper lines okay: ^.*pPrev.*$
In the Replace field, I leave it blank thinking the line should deleted (i.e. replaced with nothing), but the newline and endline characters remain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the "Extended" setting in the Replace window (not "Regular expression": I'm sure there's a way to do it with Regular expression, but using "Extended" works fine). 
Enter "`.pPrev.\r\n`" in the "Find what" field, and leave the "Replace what" field blank. This will include the \r\n characters in the match and delete the whole line.

Comment: Does not work anymore in later Notepad++ versions (5.9.2 UNICODE tested)

Comment: It seems like they keep pulling good features from Notepad++.  First, the FunctionList plugin and now this. :(

Comment: still working. If not, delete \n first and then delete \r

Comment: I came here looking for info on how to remove line breaks and \r\n worked for me like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the "Regular expression search" option in the Find & Replace window:

Define the regex Find string that you are looking for, and include the `\xd?\xa` "end-of-line" characters in the match.

If want to delete these line brakes then leave the Replace string blank.

Note, the carriage return character is optional (`\xd?`), because you could have lines ending with no carriage return and only a line feed character `\xa`.

Comment: This worked for me where all other answers (pertaining to Notepad++) did not. I'm using v7.5.1

Answer (score 1):

The general principle whichever editor you're using is that you need to include the new line characters (`\r\n` assuming Windows line endings) in your search so that they will be included in the replacement and thus removed.

In Notepad++ this is made a bit more confusing by the 2 different search and replace commands. See this Wiki page for details: [Replacing Newlines in Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Replacing_Newlines)

I only had an old version of Notepad++ to hand so had to use Extended Search (accessed via ^R), making sure Regular Expr was unticked and using ^M to insert the new line character into the Find field. However if you make sure you're using Notepad++ 4.9 or later you should be able to use `\r` and `\n` in the regexp mode.

Comment: I'm not able to use `\r` or `\n` in RegEx mode (version 5.8.6).  They only work in Extended mode for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually select the newline by moving your cursor from the end of one line to the beginning of the next:

```
first line(from here)
(to here)decond line
third line
```

Then press ctrl+h while the new line is selected, and replace with nothing. This will delete all the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Notepad++, but you can always do it with gVim. The command is like this:

```
%g/^.pPrev.$/d
```

You can [download gVim here](http://www.vim.org/download.php) if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Wing said about 10 years ago.. I use the following to tidy up with a 'search and delete line' regex function in NP++

`<search text>\r?\n?`

In Wing's example: `<search text>\xd?\xa`

`\x` matches a hex code that corresponds to its ASCII counterpart

`\xd` (or `\x0d`) is used in Wing's example, instead of `\r` in my example

`\xd` means 'use hexadecimal d', which is 13 in decimal, and in ASCII '13' is a carriage return `\r`

Similarly for `\xa` (or `\x0a`), hexadecimal 'a' is 10 in decimal, which is a new line feed `\n` in ASCII.

See https://www.asciitable.com/ for all the ascii codes

The '`?`'s just make them optional

So use either of these in regex mode:

`<search text>\r?\n?`

or

`<search text>\xd?\xa?` (same thing as `<search text>\x0d?\x0a?`)

For example, I often strip unnecessary lines from online courses' table of contents:

```
Original text:

Dictionaries, Part I
checkmark circle
6m 25s
```

```
In NPP++

Regex mode ticked
Find what: checkmark circle\r?\n?
Replace with:
```

```
New text:

Dictionaries, Part I
6m 25s
```

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.